# error "connection refused" when trying to access to a php page stored on localhost from android app

Tags: java, php, android, mobile

i am trying to make my first demo app which communicates with remote server. i have a php project setup on localhost and trying a access a php page from android app. when i try to run and access the page i get the error "connection refused" by the app and it stops running. to access the page i am passing "my_ip_address/folder_name/file_name.php" as url . when i give the same link in browser i get the desired data but not in case when i try to connect it through mobile app. i am running the app on my own android mobile .

i have found some same questions but unfortunately because of low points couldn't paste my question to that thread. I also tried out giving the url as "10.0.2.2:8080/folder_name/file_name.php" but it didn't help. i have also updated the manifest file to access the internet. the other solution i found is "my_ip/folder_name/file_name.php" which i am already trying. it wll be great if anyone could help me here.

Thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: Try with default port i.e. 80. so your url becomes "10.0.2.2/folder_name/file_name.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your AndroidManifest file you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
2. Your android device is connected to same network where is located your web server
3. Your firewall doesn't blocking incoming connections
4. Your url is correct (scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id): e.g. `http://10.0.2.2/folder_name/file_name.php`

Comment: `http://10.0.2.2/folder_name/file_name.php` should be used when using emulator and trying to access a server running on localhost of that pc.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 for default AVD and 10.0.3.2 for Genymotion

Comment: Thanks Petr... i cross checked the four points mentioned . everything looks good but still it throws error "connection refused" :(

Comment: Hey Petr, it was resolved. i restarted my wifi which caused change in IP address... Above is the correct solution for this. Thanks Man :) !